# APIリファレンス(/operators/{operator_id}/token)への質問です

Tags: soracom

APIリファレンスについて、

[/operators/{operator_id}/token](https://dev.soracom.io/jp/docs/api/#!/Operator/generate_operator_token)の記述に、

StatusCode == 400 の場合は、

> API トークンが無効（再度認証を行う必要がある）

とありますが、
Tokenのtimeout設定によりすでにTokenが無効になっていたり、
Tokenそのものが無効なもの(一部文字列を削除するなど)であると、

StatusCode == 403 であり、

```
{
  "code": "AUM0013",
  "message": "Invalid JWT."
}
```

という内容でRequest bodyが返ってきます。
仕様については、以上のものが正しいのでしょうか？

StatucCode == 400 となるレスポンスが返ってくる条件は、
OperatorIdをpathに設定しなかった場合に返ってきます。

Answer (score 1):

トークンの有効期限が切れていたり無効なトークンである場合に Status Code == 403 が返ってきてしまう件ですが、これは 400 となるのが本来の仕様です。修正させていただきます。
レスポンス Body の内容については仕様通りです。

上記の他、ご確認いただいたように URL の Path に必要な情報が設定されていない等、リクエスト内容が誤っている場合にも 400 が返ります。

Comment: 素早いご回答ありがとうございます！助かりますm(_ _)m

Comment: 本番環境に修正版をデプロイしましたのでご確認ください。

Comment: ありがとうございますm(_ _)m

Comment: 無効なtokenリクエストを送ったところ、BadRequest(400)が返ってきました。対応ありがとうございますヽ(=´▽`=)ﾉ